# Single Content Provider or Multiple Content Providers in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design, android-contentprovider

I am kind of stuck in dilemma, I am making an application which consist of multiple tables/entities and I am using **`Content Provider`** to manage my **sql data**. Almost every table in db has a relation with other table.

Now I am really confused whether I should make a single content provider, stuff it with 9,10 tables and use it. Or should I make a **separate content provider** for every single table and use it.

I can handle **join** queries between tables in both ways as well. Can anyone give me **pros and cons** for both approaches? and guide me in the right direction ?

Any kind of help, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm kind of curious why you're going that route at all if you're writing a single app.  ContentProvider is meant to provide data to other applications (usually 3rd party, although sometimes your own).  If you don't need that you'll have a far simpler interface just using SQL, or a ORM layer if you really want to.

Comment: @GabeSechan 
Apart for sharing data to other applications, Content provider do make your life pretty easy, manage DB synchronization for you. The facility of Cursor loader and other loaders. My application is heavily based on fetching and showing the data in UI as well. So Content provider turn out to be the best option in that case.

Comment: @RobertHarvey 
Not 10 but lets say 4 or 5. You can image how ugly would a content provider start looking if there are 10 tables added to it. 
Even if i make a separate provider, database and use interfaces. 
Its still too much of a code in a single file. I might be wrong here , that why i am asking for suggestions.

Comment: We'll just agree to disagree there-  I find a custom made helper class orders of magnitude better than the way too generic Content API.  To the point where I'd flunk a code review that used it if it wasn't for external consumption.  You're really making your life much more difficult than needed.  The fact you even had to post this question is proof of it.  Even the Google API on ContentProvider basically says don't use it for internal use.

Comment: haha point taken, so lets just say If I have to stick with Content providers. What suggestion would you like to give me then? 
related to the question ?

Comment: @GabeSechan what about cursor loaders, custom search suggestions, sync adapters? they all needs a custom content provider, i agree that last two can be used not very often but cursor loader is a base stuff in any app that uses sqlite db

Comment: @pskink I'd spend the 30 seconds it takes to write an AsyncTask to do it for me, which would take less time than writing around Google's API for it.  Google's stuff there is so generic that it all requires writing subclasses for anyway-  once you hit that point you provide no value with the generic class, you'll get better performance for less effort doing it on your own.  It takes more time to look up the API for CursorLoader than it does to rewrite the entire useful part of its functionality.

Comment: @GabeSechan loaders are not just async tasks, more here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: @pskink Sure it is.  It loads data in the background.  That's an AsyncTask that can be written in under a minute.  Look at the implementation here:  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.java#AsyncTaskLoader  90% of the code in there is either debug or a light wrapper around AsyncTask.  Don't get me wrong, the *pattern* is useful.  But the class itself is cumbersome because it tries to be too generic, you end up having to just as much work as writing your own.  But we're hijacking here.

Answer (score 1):

If the tables relate to each other and presumably you would like to do joins then you should do one content provider and not multiple. I assume if the tables relate then you will be wanting to do joins on data or at the very least enforce foreign key constraints.

Also for doing joins the best way. In my opinion to do them is to create a view. Treat it kinda like a table. You can query it like a table also. Just my advice. If your still interested in this I can go into more detail.